# Using ACF gutenberg blocks in parent/child themes

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have multiple sites which uses a certain parent-theme and all the customisation comes from child themes.

I have most of the blocks registered in parent theme, but in some cases I need to customize them in child theme.

When I register a new block in child theme, I get an error that it's already registered. Is there a way to override the block settings and/or somekind of acf_deregister_block_type function?

Comment: I guess that you have some sort of function in your parent themes functions.php or similar - So could you not make that pluggable - like `if ( ! function_exists( 'my_awesome_function' ) ) {` etc. then you could overwrite that function in your child theme.